# Jenkins failed with error code 1062

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reactjs, jenkins

My recent build on jenkins is failed with error :

```
AppCmd.exe exited on sitename.com with error code 1062.
```

All steps including checking out code, getting packages from nuget, npm, bower, sass compilation, application compilation, webpack compilation, minification & bundling, sql update is ran successfully and error occurs after that.

Faced it first time not sure what it is and how to resolve.

Application is using react, ASP.net, WebAPI and SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some issue in IIS. Somehow application pools were failed to start in IIs reset & application was not able to start. Started app pools manually & running jenkins worked fine afterwards.